# Shadow duplicated in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with shadows in three.js but I have an issue, that is the shadow is projecting on two faces of a mesh, like this.

[image]

the shadow of the "head" of my actor is on two faces of the red polygon, i don't know why, I am using `THREE.HemisphereLight` and `THREE.DirectionalLight` also the properties `castShadow` and `receiveShadow`

Comment: See if this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070747/three-js-shadow-map-shows-on-back-side-issue-is-there-a-work-around

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2454

You could break your red bar into 2 objects, one that receives shadows and one that doesn't. Or simply use a different material for each face.

Or adjust the shadow camera box so it doesn't encompass both sides of the red bar. That way  you'd control how far the shadow is cast.