# Lighting not working properly with MeshLambertMaterial in THREE js

Tags: three.js

I am creating 3D rooms with Three.js. I have used MeshLambertMaterial as wall materials. When I add a PointLight into the room it is working properly. But when I add another bulb outside of the room it it not working.

```
var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xD3D3D3, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
```

Here is a reproducing test-case:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

var bulbLight;
var bulbLight2;
var bulbLightDirection = 1;

function addLights() {
  var bulbGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.02, 16, 8);
  bulbLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffee88, 2, 100, 2);
  bulbLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffee88, 2, 100, 2);

  var bulbMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    emissive: 0xffffee,
    emissiveIntensity: 1,
    color: 0x000000
  });
  bulbLight.add(new THREE.Mesh(bulbGeometry, bulbMat));
  bulbLight.position.set(-0.5, 0.6, -1.5);
  bulbLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.01;
  bulbLight.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(bulbLight);
  
  bulbLight2.add(new THREE.Mesh(bulbGeometry, bulbMat));
  bulbLight2.position.set(-0.5, 0.6, -1.5);
  bulbLight2.shadow.camera.near = 0.01;
  bulbLight2.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(bulbLight2);

  var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xddeeff, 0x0f0e0d, 0.02);
  scene.add(hemiLight);
}

function addFloor() {
  var floorMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xD3D3D3, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

  var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(20, 20);
  //floorGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
  //floorGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
  var floorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMat);
  floorMesh.receiveShadow = true;
  floorMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2.0;
  scene.add(floorMesh);
}

function addWalls() {
  var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xD3D3D3, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
  var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 2, 5);
  //boxGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
  //boxGeometry.computeVertexNormals();
  var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, cubeMat);
  boxMesh.position.set(0.1, 0.25, -0.5);
  boxMesh.castShadow = true;
  boxMesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(boxMesh);

  var boxMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, cubeMat);
  boxMesh2.position.set(0.5, 0.25, 0.5);
  boxMesh2.castShadow = true;
  boxMesh2.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(boxMesh2);
}

function addControls() {
  var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();
}

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
  camera.position.x = -4;
  camera.position.z = 4;
  camera.position.y = 2;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  addLights();
  addFloor();
  addWalls();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
  renderer.gammaInput = true;
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  addControls();

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

  bulbLight.position.x += (bulbLight.direction === 1) ? 0.01 : -0.01;

  if (bulbLight.position.x > 1) bulbLight.direction = 0;
  if (bulbLight.position.x < -1) bulbLight.direction = 1;

}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

What is wrong here ?

MeshPhongMaterial gives the same result. But working with MeshStandardMaterial

Comment: please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code and don't paste links to web code-editors.

Comment: @Unlockedluca In this case, I have to provide working code. That is why I have added jsfiddle.

Comment: Jonarya, you can create a "snippet" in StackOverflow, which is the same thing. Look in the toolbar of the post editor. The buttons are, from left to right: Bold, Italic, Insert Hyperlink, Insert Quote, Insert Code, Insert Image, **Insert Snippet**. You _may_ link to external sites, **BUT** you should also paste your code here, because someday that external link might change, and your question would lose all context.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have found a bug with `MeshLambertMaterial` where it's miscalculating multiple shadows. I played with your code for a while, and from the looks of it, the material is performing a multiply operation, where it only illuminates where both lights shine, but not when only one shines:

```
1 x 1 = 1;
1 x 0 = 0;
0 x 0 = 0;
```

In reality, lights should be calculated in an additive way:

```
1 + 1 = 2;
1 + 0 = 1;
0 + 0 = 0;
```

The only solution I found was changing the walls and floor material to `MeshPhongMaterial`. Also, you probably don't need `THREE.DoubleSide` on the walls.

```
var floorMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xD3D3D3, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xD3D3D3 });
```

[See working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/dLh2sufh/6/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing are self-shadowing artifacts due to the fact that you have both `receiveShadow` and `castShadow` set to `true` for your mesh.

Self-shadowing artifacts can be reduced by adjusting `light.shadow.bias`. Unfortunately, doing so can cause other artifacts.

Shadows can be tricky. I suggest you google the topic and make sure you understand all the issues involved.

Also, `MeshLambertMaterial` is limited in how it handles shadows. I would use `MeshStandardMaterial` if you have an environment map, or `MeshPhongMaterial` otherwise.

three.js r.87

Comment: Here I have 2 walls (boxes) and 2 bulbs. Right side wall and floor do not affect by left fixed bulb. So when moving bulb reach right side this self-shadowing thing should not affect, isn't it?

Comment: Remember, point lights have six shadow cameras. There can be self-shadowing artifacts for any type of light when the light rays are nearly parallel to a face. In your case, you get parallel rays in four directions when the light is close to the wall... These artifacts are sometimes hard to understand without a lot of investigative work -- but that is my best guess as to what is going on. Also, there is [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600256/three-js-shadow-on-opposite-side-of-light), which you may be seeing.